# Multiple <div> display in one line, using maximum space available

Tags: html, css, width

I have three `<div>` elements that have a parent `<div>`. Parent `<div>` takes up the whole screen, but has a set height. I need all three `<div>` elements within it to have the exact same width, but at the same time take as much space as they can without line break, but have no luck. Is it somehow achievable, maybe using some other method?

Here's the HTML code i have right now:

```css
.banner_container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 510px;
  max-width: 1230px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.banner {
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0px;
}
.banner:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_container">
  <div class="banner">Banner 1</div>
  <div class="banner">Banner 2</div>
  <div class="banner">Banner 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: for the 3 div the same size, did you try the css width:33%; they will have the same size and will each take 33% of the parent div width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the child elements a percentage width, rather than a fixed (min/max-)width.

Without the margins, it would just be a straightforward ~33% width for each.

However, with the margins, you're going to need to use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to get ~33% of the remaining space.

And the calculation you'd need would be: `(100% - 2 * 15px) / 3` = `(100% - 30px) / 3` = `33.333% - 10px`.

```css
.banner_container{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:510px;
    max-width:1230px;
}
.banner{
    background-color:grey;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:calc(33.333% - 10px);
}
.banner_container>:nth-child(2){
    margin:0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_container">
    <div class="banner">Banner 1</div>
    <div class="banner">Banner 2</div>
    <div class="banner">Banner 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I wanted, and worked perfectly.

Comment: @Vlad - Note that `calc()` is still considered experimental.

Comment: Indeed. It's still very well supported, though, as you can see on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Answer (score -1):

```
.banner {

width: 33%  

}
```

Might want to consider removing the min-width max-width code so that this doesn't break on devices smaller and larger than the min/max sizes.